# How to set the background of a modally presented UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, background-image

I have a UIViewController that is modally presented by a page curl transition. 
When I put a fullscreen UIImageView in the view of the presented controller the page curl goes up to upper edge of the screen. 
On this modally presented view I only want to use half of the screen so the page curl should only come up until half off the screen. 
I want to set the background of this view and meanwhile avoiding that the page curl goes up to the upper edge of the screen. 
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];